# Add Meta Web Apps to the data dump

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump, per-site-meta

Unlike the other per-site metas, Meta Web Apps [wasn't included](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-10/) in the October data dump.

Comment: It isn't listed in the post, so I'm guessing it's intentional.

Comment: @Simon, Fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All per site metas will be included with their respective parent site.

Answer (score 1):

The admins have stated that sites will only be added to the data dump when they're big enough to contribute meaningfully. Web Apps was just added last go-round, and today it has 2301 questions. Meta Web Apps only has 182 questions. Even if they are planning to include it, it's not big enough yet.

Comment: Maybe, but Meta Web Apps isn't its own site though.  It is tied to Web Apps.  MSF has 219 questions and MSU has 445.  They aren't exactly big either.

Comment: @rchern, perhaps the cutoff is 200? I don't know. I actually searched for the "we'll add sites once they're big enough" source after posting this answer and couldn't find it.

Comment: I feel like I've seen it previously, but I'm not sure it should apply to per-site metas.